# C'est "C'est chaud !" trop familier pour le travail ?

Tags: expressions, usage, registre-familier, france

Je voudrais savoir si l'expression "**C'est chaud !**" est trop familière pour l'environnement de travail, c'est-à-dire, si je risque d'être vulgaire.

À remarquer que je l'utilise avec des collègues auxquels je tutoie, avec lesquels j'ai un bon rapport et avec lesquels je fais des blagues. Donc, avec eux je n'utilise pas de gros mots mais j'utilise bien d'expressions familières pas vulgaires (par exemple, "n'importe quoi", "bosser", "c'est le bazar", etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si tu entretiens des rapports "familiers" avec tes collègues, "C'est chaud" aura le même degré de familiarité que les expressions auxquelles tu fait allusion ("bosser", "c'est le bazar", etc.)

Cela reste du familier et non du vulgaire, à la différence de "C'est la merde" qui là, est plutôt vulgaire, dans un contexte similaire.

Comment: Merci G.P. C'était une question simple mais j'avais besoin de le savoir quand même. Merci également pour l'expression vulgaire équivalente.